# WaitForSingleObject : how to get handle from _beginthreadex

Tags: c++, multithreading

hello guys this is my code

```
#include "StdAfx.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <windows.h>
#include <process.h>  


unsigned int __stdcall threadproc(void* lparam)
{
    std::cout << "my thread" << std::endl;
    return 0;
}


int main()
{
    unsigned  uiThread1ID = 0;

    uintptr_t th = _beginthreadex(NULL, 0, threadproc, NULL, 0, &uiThread1ID);
     WaitForSingleObject(th, INFINITE/*optional timeout, in ms*/);
    return 0;
}
```

But i get the following error message

error C2664: 'WaitForSingleObject' : cannot convert parameter 1 from 'uintptr_t' to 'HANDLE'

Could someone please help me ?

Comment: Just cast the return value of _beginthreadex to (HANDLE).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to cast the `uintptr_t` to type `HANDLE`, this is demonstrated in the second example on [this page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kdzttdcb.aspx), more specifically:

```
HANDLE hThread;
hThread = (HANDLE)_beginthreadex(...);
```

(note: this is only legal with `_beginthreadex`)