# is it safe to cast uintptr_t returned by _beginthread to HANDLE?

Tags: c++, multithreading, winapi, visual-c++

1)The answer from this post [WaitForSingleObject : how to get handle from _beginthreadex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12605966/waitforsingleobject-how-to-get-handle-from-beginthreadex) say that it is only legal to cast uintptr_t returned _beginthreadex to type HANDLE, then is it not safe to convert uintptr_t returned _beginthread to type HANDLE?

2)We have cast like below in a 32-bit application and it seems to be working well, will I run into any issues when I convert this app to 64-bit?
HANDLE thread = (HANDLE)_beginthread(checkThread, 0, &thrVal);

3) Is it worth to convert all the _beginthread calls to _beginthreadex?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the answer to the question you linked is misleading, or at least incomplete. According to the docs for `beginthread()` and `beginthreadex()`:

> If successful, each of these functions returns a handle to the newly
>   created thread

The difference between the two is that threads started by `beginthread()` close their own handles when they exit. So it's not safe to wait on a handle returned by `beginthread()` because it may have been closed or recycled by the time you wait on it. However if you have control over the thread you launched (by using some other form of synchronisation) you could call `DuplicateHandle()` to get a handle that is safe to wait on.

In an x64 build, `uintptr_t` is defined as a 64 bit value:

```
typedef unsigned __int64    uintptr_t;
```

So casting this to a `HANDLE` in this case is safe and is indeed what you're meant to do.

`_beginthreadex()` gives you more control over the new thread, including the ability to start it in a suspended state, and retrieve the thread ID. It also returns a `HANDLE` that **you** are responsible for closing, which means it's safe to wait on it. It's a more useful, versatile function, but if you don't have a need for those additional features there's no reason to switch just for the sake of it.

Comment: While you answered the question whether a `uintptr_t` can hold a `HANDLE` value, you failed to read the documentation carefully enough. Your advice is in conflict with the documentation.

Comment: @IInspectable: The reason you can't wait on the `HANDLE` isn't because it's not a `HANDLE`, it's because it may have been closed out from underneath you. It's still a valid `HANDLE` for as long as the thread is running.

Comment: I fully understand why it isn't safe. You still should not say "Yes!" to an answer asking whether it is safe, when in general it isn't. Granted, though, you didn't say to unconditionally use the returned value the same way you can with the value returned from `_beginthreadex`, but provided helpful rationale.

Comment: @IInspectable: Where did I say "Yes!"? Did you actually read my answer?

Comment: The just-as-nasty scenario is the handle being replaced by another thread. before you even use a syncro-api. I.e. the started thread runs, finishes, closes and a new one starts with the same handle address. In which case it is *still* a valid handle, but not what you think it is. Personally I have distaste for MS for giving us two versions of that function in the first place. But regardless, I still concur with Jonathan. The handle is valid so long as the original thread is running (and for the record, I *never* use `_beginthread` regardless, especially now that we have `std::thread` =)

Comment: @Jonathan This is getting tedious, but did you even read my comment? At any rate, you are promoting to violate a contract. Disasters happen, because people **think** they know what they are doing.

Comment: @IInspectable: the original question was "is it safe to cast uintptr_t returned by _beginthread to HANDLE". The answer to that is yes, it is safe. A further question, not asked by the OP, was is it safe to use that handle. The answer that is yes, it is sometimes safe. Your answer "No it's not safe under any circumstances" is frankly, wrong.

Comment: @Jonathan Why would you ever want a `HANDLE`? For the synchronization APIs. The OP even mentioned `WaitForSingleObject`. Plus, I didn't say that it's never safe. The documentation did. It's contractual. Even if it is safe, under certain circumstances, today it may not be safe tomorrow. If you think this is wrong, send a defect report to Microsoft.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to use the Windows synchronization APIs you need a `HANDLE` you control. Using the `uintptr_t` returned from `_beginthread` cannot safely be cast to a `HANDLE` value for use with the synchronization APIs. The documentation for [_beginthread, _beginthradex](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kdzttdcb.aspx) is pretty clear here (emphasis mine):

> You can also use the thread handle that's returned by _beginthreadex with the synchronization APIs, **which you cannot do with _beginthread**.

If you don't want to rely on undocumented behavior you must use `_beginthreadex` if you need a `HANDLE` value for use with the synchronization APIs.

Comment: It's a valid `HANDLE` for as long as the thread is running. You failed to read the docs carefully enough :)

Comment: @Jonathan It's a valid `HANDLE` for *some* time. That you do not in general control. At any rate, the documentation is clear. And the implementation can change at any point in time.